# sending a value to another cardpane

Tags: java

I am trying to send a simple value to another form and i cant seem to get it working right. What happens is that when i get to the form and i punch in numbers it displays right in that page. But when i click confirm and i go to the next pane it doesnt carry over anything i pressed.

EG. If i set the label to 109.99 as a default and then click clear and put in my own numbers like 59.99 and click confirm the next page will only grab the default 109.99. Obviously this isnt the right way to do it but i cant figure out how. Its driving me insane as im stuck on this for 2 weeks.

I am mentally exhausted over this and frustrated at the same time. If someone can show me a working modified example and explain where i went wrong that would be great. I emphasize on the working example. I learn best when i see it in action.

Purchase.java https://pastebin.com/YG1sXegk

Pconfirm.java https://pastebin.com/C0MV8xnt

relevant code is here...

purchase.java

```
private JLabel lblamnt;
private String camnt;

btn0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        lblamnt.setText(lblamnt.getText() + "0");
        camnt = camnt + "0";
    }
});
```

The getter..

```
public String amount() {
    return lblamnt.getText();
}
```

pconfirm.java

```
private JLabel lblgamnt;
Purchase ppp = new Purchase();

//Temp Variables
private Double cost = Double.parseDouble(ppp.amount());
```

Comment: The labels in the two classes may have the same name but they are not identical. You must transfer the value from one object to the other. You could use a listener for that. The first page could send an event to the parentForm. There all pages (or at least the one you are interested in) have to be registered as listeners. The parentForm can send the received event to all listeners. Then the second panel can react to the event and set the new value.

Comment: can you demonstrate an example so i can see what you mean?

Comment: the label is not the same one is lblamnt and the other is lblgamnt

Comment: @RalfRenz Can you please demonstrate a working example of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. Was not passing method to the class.